# How do we judge the flow of time from our frame of reference?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, time, observers

Is there a means to determine our frame of reference on past events in space-time? How do I know my current reference (today) is the same as it was two days ago for the rate at which time is perceived? A satellite sits in space and has an atomic clock while another is on Earth there will be a perceivable change over time between the two clocks. If we could, somehow, view past events in the same way would we see a constant change over time or would that change be faster or slower from our current, changing frame of reference?

How do I know the day two days ago was as long as the day today, from my current frame of reference?

Comment: I can't make head or tail of what this question is meant to mean.

Comment: Your words make no sense to me at all.

Comment: essentially, this question boils down to asking how to determine if we have at all shifted to a different inertial/gravitational frame of reference since some previous time even if we include effects from GR. It's perfectly clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you "look in a mirror" (a distant object that is stationary with respect to you), then events reflected by this mirror would reflect "time gone by". So if you have a clock sending pulses at (what you believe to be) 1 MHz, and you look at the pulses as they come back a day later - if our entire universe had changed clocks, the return frequency would appear different.

But that's not what we observe.

Another example: the spectral lines of hydrogen from distant stars (representing the concept of time "a long time ago" still appear in the same place as they do today.

Wouldn't either of these experiments be sufficient to conclude time isn't changing (despite [what Bob Dylan might have us believe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7qQ6_RV4VQ)...)?

Comment: Good enough evidence for me.

Comment: @Floris what about red shifts, such as observed as evidence for dark energy, could that be explained by differences in time?

Comment: BOOM! Take that, Bob Dylan!

Comment: @Floris wouldn't your example only prove observational uniformity and not a consistency in the changes in time itself?

Comment: @NationWidePants I am not sure I understand your question. “Distance” allows us to put two measurements of “time” side by side and we don’t see them shifting relative to each other (other than due to presence of mass/dark matter/ or velocity). That isn’t proof - but it supports the null hypothesis. Until we find an example that it is changing I feel comfortable to go with the reasonable hypothesis it isn’t . But that’s just me.

Comment: @Floris As a thought experiment: if two jets are moving uniformly, altering speed occasionally, the results of experiments shouldn't change. how does this prove the speed didn't change during the experiment?

Comment: @NationWidePants “altering speed”... at the same time and place or different? If “same”, it proves nothing; if “different”, the acceleration will create momentary shifts in observed signals!

Comment: @Floris My point being, frame of reference in time matters if everything else changes with you. If time speeds up and slows down uniformly you wouldn't realize it if, from your perspective, it's uniform, but from someone able to see it from another perspective it was not uniform with their frame of reference. So your example doesn't prove that it didn't change, only that it didn't change for your frame of reference.

Comment: @Floris two rockets are moving uniformly, speeding up as they move. One rocket is projecting a laser on the other. The faster they move the greater than angle is necessary to strike the other rocket. If this change was a change in the speed through time rather than the speed of movement through space, since all 3 parts, the two rockets and the laser, are all in time, so it is not clear to me that you would notice a change. Am I incorrect in this assumption?

Comment: What i mean is, a change in the speed though the temporal dimension would only be observable if one of those parts doesn't move through time like the others, from the above example, at least thats how it would seem to me. Is that assumption incorrect?

Comment: Your rockets would experience acceleration. Once you introduce non-inertial frames of reference you expect time to change.